# best way to convert flow to live data

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I am implementing search from Unsplash api and data will be updated on the basis of search

**GalleryViewModel.kt**

```
@HiltViewModel
class GalleryViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val fetchPhotoUseCase:FetchPhotoUseCase,
    @Assisted state: SavedStateHandle
) :ViewModel(){

    companion object{
        private const val CURRENT_QUERY = "current_query" // key
        private const val DEFAULT_QUERY = "cats"
    }

    private val currentQuery = state.getLiveData(CURRENT_QUERY, DEFAULT_QUERY)
    
    val photos = currentQuery.switchMap { queryString ->
        liveData {
            fetchPhotoUseCase.execute(queryString).collect {  
                emit(it)
            }
        }
    }

   fun searchPhotos(query: String) {
    currentQuery.value = query
   }
}
```

**FetchPhotoUseCase.kt**

```
class FetchPhotoUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: UnSplashRepository
) : UseCaseWithParams<String,Flow<PagingData<UnsplashPhoto>>>(){
    override suspend fun buildUseCase(params: String): Flow<PagingData<UnsplashPhoto>> {
        return repository.getSearchResult(params)
    }
}
```

`FetchPhotoUseCase` is in the domain layer. It returns flow so I change flow to live data in switchmap lambda.

Am I doing it right or is there a better way to achieve it..

**Edit**

I have updated my code to work on both dispatchers like below..

```
suspend fun getPhotos(queryString: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        fetchPhotoUseCase.execute(queryString)
    }

    fun getImages(queryString: String) = liveData(Dispatchers.Main) {
        getPhotos(queryString).collect {
            emit(
                it.map { unsplash ->
                    unSplashMapper.mapFromEntity(unsplash)
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a handy method [`asLiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#aslivedata), which already implements of what you have written:

```
val photos = currentQuery.switchMap { queryString ->
    fetchPhotoUseCase.execute(queryString).asLiveData(Dispatchers.Main)
}
```

Dependency to use `asLiveData()` extension function:

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0"

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

Comment: What if I want to execute Use case(flow) in Dispatcher.IO and liveData in Dispatcher.Main to populate in UI thread (I mean a list)

Comment: see my edit as well @Sergey

Comment: `asLiveData(Dispatchers.Main)`

Comment: val test = categoryUseCase.execute().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).asLiveData(Dispatchers.Main)
It said suspend fuction could only be called from coroutine or other suspend function

Comment: I have also tried like val test = viewModelScope.launch {
        categoryUseCase.execute().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).asLiveData(Dispatchers.Main)
    }
But it returns a job . How could I return a liveData from it